# Keep comunication with python script running on server

Tags: python, node.js, websocket

This is what I developed so far. First, my websocket server:

```js
// app.js
const spawn = require('child_process');
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 })

wss.on('connection',ws => {
  ws.on('message', message => {
    const python = spawn('python', ['-u', 'main.py', message])
    python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      // Pipe data from python script ...
      dataToSend = data.toString('utf8');
      ws.send(dataToSend)
     });
     python.on('error', err => {
       console.log(err)
     })
  })
  ws.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Client has disconected')
  })
}).on('error', err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

It basics uses `child_process` to spawn a python script passing a `message` that was sent from client.
`-u` is passed in order to flush python script prints, so it can be streamed out on `python.stdout` and sent to client.

This is my python script that is being invoked from app.js websocket server:

```py
# main.py
import time, sys
i = int(sys.argv[1])
while i > 0:
    print(i)
    i-=1
    time.sleep(1)
    # this while is just anexemple of some pre-script process
    # (for exemple, signin on user account)

# after signin...
print('input something from client: ')
x = input()

while True:
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
    # use input x variable
    # here is where my code happens and the program keeps executing
    pass
```

As you can see, I'm using `message` passed on `spawn()` from server to keep my first `while` alive. It's just an exemple that I will need this kind of input from user.

**Keep your atention on `x = input()` because that is my main problem**

And finally, my client websocket

```js
// client.js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
    let someClientInfo = 2
    console.log("sending data...");
    socket.send(someClientInfo);

};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log('Output of python script: ' + event.data.toString('utf-8'));
};

socket.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
};
```

It basics pass this first argument `someClientInfo`, and then receive python script output like this:

```
sending data...

Output of python script: 2 

Output of python script: 1

Output of python script: input something from client:
```

Of course, when client receive this last line, it keeps getting stuck because he can't input anything from his side. He's just receiving a stream of outputs from python.

Anyone knows if it's possible to pass this second input to my running python script? I'm starting to think that maybe it's impossible but I can't thing about another way to do that. If it is something that `child_process` can't do, what way should I look for?

My main purpose is to **keep an alive communication with an python script running on server, so I can pass this inputs from client to python.**

I want to be able to disconnect from this socket, and then, connect again and keep receiving python script outputs. So far I couldn't find a way to do that too.

My main script can't be inside the server code (maybe if you tought about a basic implementation of flask, or something like that), because I want to be able to start multiple scripts and each client user should be able to keep iteracting with his own python script running on server. Each user will have his own `main.py`

So far I didn't tought about how I'll keep all this processess running on server, or even if it's safe to do something like that. Any advice about that will be very apreciated and I'll be very thankfull about too.

Comment: "I won't to be able to start multiple scripts " --- I think you can, have you thought about spawning `main.py` from python and passing the connection 'object' to `main.py`? That way your client can directly send data to `main.py`.

Comment: or - if you REALLY need node.js - you can do this. first spawn `main.py` with `x`. Terminate the program once it needs `x` and return all `variables`. Respawn another `main.py`, but instead of passing `x` only, pass `main.py` (if you make a repatitive task). If your task is not 'repatitive', spawn the needed script in order. `login.py`, `comment.py`...

Comment: " each client user should be able to keep iteracting with his own python script running on server " --- Each client will keep interacting with 'the' not 'his' python script in flask. But you can send a 'cookie' to the client. Are you famliar with cookies? The 2 past 'possible' solutions are not used in production or anywhere like that...

Comment: I'm not very familliar with cookies, can I use it? I don't wan't to run it on the web, it needs to be runned on the server and keep running if user disconnect. The problem with this flask aproach is that I need singular environments for each user (config files and  stuff), so I tought that will be hard to run only one global application that control all users iteraction

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what the script must do?

Comment: An HTTP cookie (web cookie, browser cookie) is a small piece of data that a server sends to the user's web browser. The browser may store it and send it back with later requests to the same server. Typically, it's used to tell if two requests came from the same browser — keeping a user logged-in, for example. It remembers stateful information for the stateless HTTP protocol.

Comment: "I want to be able to disconnect from this socket, and then, connect again and keep receiving python script outputs." --- what time is max. allowed? This implementation will result in an easy-to-do DOS attack.

Comment: How do you save users and their 'config files'? Don't you use a database for users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell
You can spawn a python instance on node.

Comment: Hmmm, that might work. I'll try to look better on `.send()` that maybe is what i'm looking for

Comment: It worked, I used `.send()` as I said. I just created a condition that allows client to input when certaiin message is sent to him. Then I pass this message from client to the websocket, and from the websocket to python using `.send()` from `python-shell` library :)

Comment: Glad it helped! Happy coding :)